# Chilli plant leaves wrinkling

Tags: chili

The leaves on my chili plant have started wrinkling up. This is happening on even the new leaves. The plant is still flowering and producing chilis though.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Any ideas as to what is causing this? I don't think it is over watering because I only water if the soil is not damp and I have another chili plant, of a different species which is not showing these symptoms.

If it matters, I recently repotted the plants to a larger pot.

Comment: Have you looked at the undersurface and elsewhere with a magnifying lens to see if you have an insect infestation?

Comment: When you  repotted it, did you simply place the root ball into a bigger pot with additional soil on the bottom and sides or did you do something more?

Comment: @GrahamChiu no infestation, also, identical symptons on 2/3 plants.

Comment: @JimYoung apart from that, added a little organic fertilizer on the bottom layer. The soil that the plant was originally in was not the same as I added at the bottom.

Comment: My experience w leaves rolling when no infestation, has been excess of salts in the soil.  Do you ever let water run all the way through the pot?  Does it have a hole in the bottom?  Otherwise salt buildup can happen quite easily.

Comment: @gorav, yes, the pot has a hole at the bottom, and I let water run through about once a week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Using Eggplants as a proxy - they are the same family - I've never grown Chilies though) - This is probably not something to worry too about - its most likely simply due to stress (ie stress of transplanting).

It could also be related to extremes in temperature.  You may want to ensure the plants are getting adequate water, but the leaves look healthy enough.

Comment: I would agree - I often see it with new leaves, and the leaves straighten themselves out over time. Aphids can produce similar symptoms but you've checked for those.

Comment: Ah, ok. Will wait and see.

Comment: Ok, so 5 days later, newer leaves seem to be coming out straight. Looks like the stress was the reason. Wish these things came with a dashboard... sigh!